# How to add string function to XPath in Saxon?

Tags: xpath, saxon

I want to create function which will find a word in a string like

```
word(@class, 'items')
```

which will be equals to

```
fn:matches(@class, "(^|\s)items(\s|$)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what I found for XSLT 2.0

```xslt
<x:transform version="2.0"
         xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:find="http://user.com/namespace">

<x:output method="html"/>

<x:function name="find:word">
    <x:param name="src"/>
    <x:param name="word"/>
    <x:sequence select="matches($src, concat('(^|\s)', $word, '(\s|$)'))"/>
</x:function>

<x:template match="//*[find:word(@class, 'items')]">
    <x:copy>
        <x:copy-of select="@*"/>
    </x:copy>
</x:template>

</x:transform>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways you can do this, but the simplest solution is to use XQuery, which allows you to define functions within the language:

```
declare function local:word($a as xs:string, $b as xs:string) as xs:boolean {
  matches($a, concat("(^|\s)", $b, "(\s|$)"))
};
```